# Log4j MDC in Grails concurrency

Tags: grails, log4j

I have an application made in Grails 2.3.11, configure MD4 of Log4j to get extra information for each request to the application, thinking that we could have a tracking by user email for example.

The logs are integrated with logentries, and today, checking some alerts, we realized that a request from a user would appear to be that another user did it. But in reality, he logged in an email from another user.

This makes us think that there is a request concurrency problem with this log mode.

The version of Log4j is 1.2.17.

Does anyone know if there are concurrency problems in these scenarios with this type of application?

Another thing this was the implementation that you add as a grails filter, this appears for every request that is made to the application, I guess, per user session.

```
package filters

import groovy.util.logging.Log4j

import org.apache.log4j.MDC

import com.peya.restaurantportal.SecurityService
import com.peya.restaurantportal.common.constants.ControllerConstants

@Log4j
class MappedDiagnosticContextFilters {

   SecurityService securityService

   Closure filters = {
      addAdditionalRequestInfoToLogs(controller: ControllerConstants.ALL_CONTROLLERS, action: ControllerConstants.ALL_ACTIONS, controllerExclude: 'error|auth|healthCheck') {
         before = {
            MDC.clear()            
            try {
               Map sessionUser = securityService.getSessionUser()
               String email = sessionUser?.email
               String selectedRestaurantId = sessionUser?.headerPageInfo?.selectedRestaurantId
               if (email && selectedRestaurantId) {
                  MDC.put('email', "[$email]")
                  MDC.put('selectedRestaurantId', "[$selectedRestaurantId]")                  
               }
            } catch (Exception e) { 
               log.error "$e" 
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```